# Quel est le mot omis dans « Vous en avez de bonnes, vous ! » ?

Tags: pronoms, en, ellipse

> *Vous EN avez de bonnes, vous !* « Ce que vous faites ou dites est
> surprenant » (**quel est le mot omis ?**)
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, §
> 676 a, je souligne ]

Grevisse et Goosse posent la question...

Comment: *Related:* [What does "En voilà..." mean in this context?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/20340/what-does-en-voil%C3%A0-mean-in-this-context)

Answer (score 5):

(Vous en avez de bonnes/drôles) paroles/idées. [ None ]

Comment: While I appreciate the intent, I kind of feel this answer is a parody of the "don't answer in comments" rule ("It's more of a guideline, really"). It serves mainly to highlight why we sometimes answer in comments. It may be correct but lacks proportion somehow.

Comment: No worries. My comment is more of an observation on our curious insistence on the comments/answers thing than pointing out a problem. My thoughts on this in general are [here](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/689/comments-or-complete-answer/690#690).

Answer (score 1):

Cette expression s'utilise selon plusieurs variantes dont deux d'entre elles suivent.

- Vous en avez de bonnes, vous !
- Vous en avez de bonnes avec vos < reprise de ce qui vient d'être dit >. (*voir exemples*)

([Le rendez-vous de tous les dangers -  Carol Ericson · 2017](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_rendez_vous_de_tous_les_dangers/EZY6DwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22vous+en+avez+de+bonnes%22&pg=PT73&printsec=frontcover)) Donc, selon vous, c'est un banal cambriolage ? Crystal protesta en grimaçant de douleur.  — Banal ? Vous en avez de bonnes ! On n'a jamais eu ce genre de problème ici... Hein, Tate ? Le réceptionniste secoua la tête avec tant de conviction que sa courte queue-de-cheval oscilla furieusement à droite et à gauche.

([Le chemin qui menait vers vous - Laurent Latorre, ‎William Réjault · 2014](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_chemin_qui_menait_vers_vous/EuIMCwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22vous+en+avez+de+bonnes%22&pg=PT8&printsec=frontcover)) Pourquoi des contrôles ? — Pour maintenir l'ordre, j'imagine. J'en sais rien, moi. Je suis pas payée pour taper la discussion. Vous en avez de bonnes, vous. — Mais vous n'avez pas voulu en savoir plus ? Elles se redresse soudainement. — Mais savoir quoi , exactement ? Hein ? Que c'est la merde partout ? Que les camions vont et viennent comme ils peuvent ?

([Fernand, un arc en ciel sous la lune - Martial Victorain · 2017](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Fernand_un_arc_en_ciel_sous_la_lune/OgJEDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22vous+en+avez+de+bonnes%22&pg=PT51&printsec=frontcover)) Vous avez de l'arthrose et quoi d'autre ? demanda Fernand. — Vous en avez de bonnes vous, avec vos « quoi d'autre ? ». Parce que ça ne vous suffit pas ? Vous avez peut-être mieux en rayon, vous ? Et pour votre curiosité, non, j'ai pas que ça. Pensez ! Ce serait trop de veine. J'ai la prostate !

On pourrait remplacer cette expression par « Vous avez de drôles de façons de penser (avec vos) ». C'est pour cette raison qu'un bon choix pour le terme omis est « façon de penser ».

---

La dernière phrase dans ma réponse n'est pas ce qu'il convient de dire, mais je la laisse telle quelle, pour plus de clarté, et j'y apporte une correction ci-dessous.

Il n'y a pas de nom qui puisse être modifié par « bonnes » et utilisé avec « bonnes » sans  changer le sens de la phrase ; pour introduire un nom qui semble manquer et que l'on recherche en tant que terme utilisé au sens littéral, il faut supprimer « en » et « de bonnes » qui donnent à l'ensemble son caractère d'expression figée. Après cette suppression le sens de la phrase est restitué (approximativement) en introduisant « de drôles de façons de penser ». Il ne s'agit donc pas d'un terme omis mais d'un terme littéral propre à suppléer au concept nominal apparemment manquant dans la phrase initiale.

Answer (score 0):

Le CNTRL qui prend le TLFIpour base indique « histoires » pour le mot omis... tout en donnant des exemples où sa fonction est anaphorique, et omet donc...la répétition d'un mot précédent:

> J'en ai fait, j'en ai fait des farces, dans mon existence. Et on m'en a fait aussi, morbleu! et de bien bonnes. Maupassant, Contes et nouvelles,t. 2, La Farce, 1883, p. 1278. C'est ici le mot « farce » qui est le seul qui puisse compléter « bonnes.»