# Sens de « t'en fais pas d'autres »

Tags: grammaire, sens

Pourriez-vous m'expliquer la phrase « ne t'en fais pas d'autres » dans l'avant-dernière case sur [image: une page des Bidochon] ?

J'ai entendu dire « ne t'en fais pas », mais pas celle-ci.

Comment: Note that the expression in the comic strip is _t'en fais pas d'autres_, which is NOT related to the expression _ne t'en fais pas_. That little _ne_ makes a world of difference and gives rise to two completely different expressions.

Comment: Thanks and nice to see you here Frank! Could you jeter un coup d'œil à l'autre question que j'ai posé sur le forum, which is related to the verb "décider"? J'arrive pas à comprendre la syntaxe de "afin qu'il soit décidé de" et j'attends désespérément une explication...

Comment: Just edited the question. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tout d'abord il faut reconnaitre que « ne t'en fais pas d'autres » n'est pas la forme appropriée. Il s'agit de « ne pas en faire d'autres ». Dans le texte, la forme pleine est  « Tu n'en fais pas d'autres » (t'en fais pas d'autres).

Il s'agit d'une expression idiomatique familière dans laquelle la référence du pronom « en » n'est pas  définie (on a récemment considéré sur le présent site une expression similaire par sa construction ([en avoir de bonnes](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/53110/17649))). C'est une expression qui signifie que l'on reproche à quelqu'un un acte donné.

Cette expression s'utilise aussi pour *parler* de personnes à qui l'on reproche un acte donné (au lieu de les utiliser pour faire le reproche à ces personnes en personne). On n'utilise ces expressions que lorsque l'acte qui est reproché est d'une nature particulière ; il doit s'agir d'actes qui sont hors de l'ordinaire, comme des erreurs que personne ne ferait d'habitude ou  même des actes amusants mais gênants ou choquants, ou bêtes ; néanmoins, si ce sont des actes dans lesquels on reproche à qui en est l'auteur son irresponsabilité, ce ne sont jamais des actes très graves, jamais des crimes sérieux, et c'est toujours dans le contexte d'une répétition de tels actes par la personne à qui on les reproche. Le reproche  que l'on fait à la personne à qui on parle ou de qui on parle, c'est finalement qu'elle n'est capable de faire que des erreurs, des sottises (« Il a fait une sottise et il ne fait que des sottises. »).

[image]

[Thesaurus linguae gallicae: Dictionnaire phraséologique de la Langue Française
Anatole Constantin Pachalery · 1897](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Thesaurus_linguae_gallicae_Dictionnaire/Zv8sAAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22en+fait+pas+d%27+autres%22&pg=PA163&printsec=frontcover)

On ne peut pas insérer dans cette expression un nom qui semble manquer ; ces expressions ne peuvent pas s'analyser selon le sens des mots qu'elles contiennent.

- <s>Il n'en fait pas d'autres choses.</s> <s>Il n'en fait pas d'autres bêtises.</s> (*Ces constructions ne sont pas correctes ; elles ne sont que du non-sens le plus complet.*)

On ne peut pas non plus insérer ces mots en supprimant « en ».

- <s>Il ne fait pas d'autres choses.</s> <s>Il ne fait pas d'autres bêtises.</s> (*Le sens de ces formes ne correspond pas du tout au sens de la locution initiale.*)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147062/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-sens-de--ne-ten-fais-pas-dautres-); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

> « T'en fais pas d'autres bêtises » (sans « ne »). Le mari fait référence à
> la convocation oubliée par sa femme. La forme est peu académique, mais
> les Bidochon ne sont pas des personnages très éduqués, surtout lui. [ Graffito (commentaire modifié) ]

L'interprétation est la suivante :

**Tu n'en** fais pas d'autres → **Tu en** fais pas d'autres → **T'en** fais pas d'autres. (Sous entendu: *d'autres bêtises, bourdes, conneries*).

et pas :

**Ne t'en** fais pas → **T'en** fais pas. (qui signifie : *Ne te fais pas de souci, ne t'inquiètes pas*)

Comment: Peut-être utile de rajour dans ta réponse un rappel du sens de "t'en fais pas" pour bien constraster?

Comment: @Frank C'est fait. Comme c'est un *community wiki*. Tu peux aussi, encore plus que pour une réponse classique, éditer/enrichir/corriger la réponse.